# Angular page not found when it's refreshed

Tags: angular

I faced strange issue while deploying the Angular project on my local server. I built the project and copied to the webserver folder which can be accessed using: `http://localhost/angular/`

`base href` also set up and app is working fine. When I click the link, it's working, for ex: `http://localhost/angular/apartments` But if I refresh, it's gone `404` error is showing.

Comment: have you specified the SPA fallback route on your server?

Comment: Angular plays with the URL, but when you refresh the page, your server actually thinks you're asking him the apartments page, while in fact you're asking Angular ! Two ways from that : either you declare all your routes to your server, or you use the hash like this (in your RouterModule declaration) : `RouterModule.forRoot(yourRoutes, { useHash: true })`

Answer (score 0):

if your server is apache simply create a file with a name of `.htaccess` paste this data

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /myappdirectory/
     RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . /index.html [L]  <--- get the index.html file path starting from public html folder
 </IfModule>
```

update the last line according to the command

save and then refresh your page. luckily your page works

For IIS server follow this link

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/02/24/angular-2-refresh-without-404-in-node-iis